# Add multiple records in DB with increment on PK variable

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-insert

I am inserting a lot of records in one table. If I insert only 1 record of data this works well.
When I add a second set of values to be inserted or more I get an error message below. I am not sure a if this can be approached in a different way.
At the moment the last `PK` in the facility tbl is (299461) , (299462) gets generated with the first set of insert vales.  The `@tempfacilityID` should be generated by an increment of 1
for every record inserted. If there is a different approach regarding this, please advise me. This approach seems not to be working and it gives me an error with the `@tempfacilityID` variable.

```
Error Message
    "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_FacilityData'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Facility'. The duplicate key value is (299462).
    The statement has been terminated.
    "

    Begin transaction 

    SET IDENTITY_INSERT Facility ON
    DECLARE @tempfacilityID int
    SELECT @tempfacilityID = MAX(facilityID)+ 1 FROM Facility 

    DECLARE @tempCategoryID int
    SELECT @tempCategoryID = CategoriesServicesID 
    FROM CategoriesServicesList
    inner join CategoriesList on CategoriesList.CategoryID = CategoriesList.CategoryID
    where CategoriesList.CategoryID = '10' and CategoriesServicesList.CategoriesServicesID = '5'

    INSERT INTO Facility (
           [FacilityID]
          ,[CategoriesServicesID]
          ,[FacilityName]
          ,[BuildingNumber]
          ,[Address]
          ,[Address2]
          ,[Borough]
          ,[area]
          ,[Latitude]
          ,[Longitude]
          ,[Phone]
          ,[AdditionalInfo]
          ,[StartDate]
          ,[EndDate]
          ,[Monday]
          ,[Tuesday]
          ,[Wednesday]
          ,[Thursday]
          ,[Friday]
          ,[Saturday]
          ,[Sunday]
          ,[IsActive]
          ,[Website]
    )
    VALUES(
    @tempfacilityid
    ,@tempCategoryID
    ,'Friends Equality'
    ,111
    ,'111 Brewer Street'
    , NULL
    , 'stan Isl'
    , 12359
    ,90.8594712
    ,-37.8951468
    ,'(646) 845-9868'
    ,'<b>Friendships start at a young age.</p>'
    ,'1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'
    ,'1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'
    ,''
    ,''
    ,''
    ,''
    ,''
    ,''
    ,''
    ,1
    ,'www.CareHand.org'
    )
     ,
    union all

    Values(

    @tempfacilityid
    ,@tempCategoryID
    ,'Self Care(specific)'
    ,189
    ,'189 Jaysone Street'
    , NULL
    , 'honran'
    , 105552
    ,26.7143459
    ,-73.992332
    ,'(212) 579-4658'
    ,'Self Awareness'
    ,'1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'
    ,'1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'
    ,''
    ,''
    ,''
    ,''
    ,''
    ,''
    ,''
    ,1
    ,'www.awarenesWpeople.org'

    )
     ,
union all

Values(

@tempfacilityid
,@tempCategoryID
,'Self Care(specific)'
,536
,'536 Melrose Ave'
, NULL
, 'Woodbury'
, 12578
,66.259459
,-93.933332
,'(912) 486-9436'
,'Joyful Life'
,'1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'
,'1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'
,''
,''
,''
,''
,''
,''
,''
,1
,'www.JoyfulLiving.org'

)


SET IDENTITY_INSERT Facility OFF
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're trying to generate the FacilityID to begin with? This definitely seems like an X Y Problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to insert the same PK id 3x, that is what is generating the error.
You should omit the [FacilityID] column (since it is primary key it will auto increment, you would need to remove SET IDENTITY_INSERT Facility ON/OFF) :

```
DECLARE @tempfacilityID INT, @tempfacilityID1 INT,@tempfacilityID2 INT


DECLARE @tempCategoryID int
SELECT @tempCategoryID = CategoriesServicesID 
FROM CategoriesServicesList
inner join CategoriesList on CategoriesList.CategoryID = CategoriesList.CategoryID
where CategoriesList.CategoryID = '10' and CategoriesServicesList.CategoriesServicesID = '5'

INSERT INTO Facility (
      [CategoriesServicesID]
      ,[FacilityName]
      ,[BuildingNumber]
      ,[Address]
      ,[Address2]
      ,[Borough]
      ,[area]
      ,[Latitude]
      ,[Longitude]
      ,[Phone]
      ,[AdditionalInfo]
      ,[StartDate]
      ,[EndDate]
      ,[Monday]
      ,[Tuesday]
      ,[Wednesday]
      ,[Thursday]
      ,[Friday]
      ,[Saturday]
      ,[Sunday]
      ,[IsActive]
      ,[Website]
)
VALUES(
@tempCategoryID
,'Friends Equality'
,111
,'111 Brewer Street'
, NULL
, 'stan Isl'
, 12359
,90.8594712
,-37.8951468
,'(646) 845-9868'
,'<b>Friendships start at a young age.</p>'
,'1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'
,'1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'
,''
,''
,''
,''
,''
,''
,''
,1
,'www.CareHand.org'
)
 ,
union all

Values(
 @tempCategoryID
,'Self Care(specific)'
,189
,'189 Jaysone Street'
, NULL
, 'honran'
, 105552
,26.7143459
,-73.992332
,'(212) 579-4658'
,'Self Awareness'
,'1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'
,'1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'
,''
,''
,''
,''
,''
,''
,''
,1
,'www.awarenesWpeople.org'

)
 ,
union all

Values(
 @tempCategoryID
,'Self Care(specific)'
,536
,'536 Melrose Ave'
, NULL
, 'Woodbury'
, 12578
,66.259459
,-93.933332
,'(912) 486-9436'
,'Joyful Life'
,'1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'
,'1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'
,''
,''
,''
,''
,''
,''
,''
,1
,'www.JoyfulLiving.org'

)
```

This way no matter how many records you insert the correct new PK is generated.`enter code here`

Comment: This will have issues with concurrency unless the first `select` holds a lock on the table with a suitable [hint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-table?view=sql-server-2017). Otherwise another user may play in the same table at the same time with unpleasant results.

Comment: @Ian-Fogelman Thank you so much!!!! this worked well if it was only 3 records been inserted. There are about 50 + records to be inserted into the table.